# no-swipeback on Framework 7 not working with turn js

Tags: ionic-framework, turnjs, html-framework-7

I am using turn js for the Book app using Framework 7 - ionic where I haven't want to swipe back after the book section but after setting class no-swipeback it still redirecting to previous div

Is there any way to stop this with turn.js

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this code will help you. other wise give some code to us so we can see your logic as well as your approach.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $('#book').turn({
        display:'double',
        acceleration: true,
        elevation:50
    });
});

$(window).bind('keydown',function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==37)
        $('#book').turn('previous');
    else if (e.keyCode==39)
        $('#book').turn('next');
});
```

Comment: Hello Kaushal, this is working on page swipe for turn js on book only
but what i want is when we are on front page of book and if i try to turn it for previous page then it stuck at that moment and hangs whole application, but now i solved it using some javascript functionality, so thanks for the reply :) .

Comment: Ok KiranKumar Best Of Luck.

Comment: Hello Kaushal, how to open phonegap www folder into eclipse and run it to emulator ?

Comment: E:\ ==> Workspace\projectname\platforms\android\assets\www  in this www our all html,js,img past and run.